# Double to Int conversion in Rectangle constructor

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a zoom function for my winforms project, and it works pretty well so far. Moving the mouse over the image shows the section of it around the pointer magnified in a smaller picture box.

Now to create the smaller picture box, I need to use Graphics.DrawImage.

```
myGraphics.DrawImage(originalImg,
new Rectangle(0, 0, zWidth, zHeight),
new Rectangle(e.X*6 , e.Y*6, zWidth, zHeight),
GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

The conversion ratio between the high- and the low-res image is ~5.863340, but the Rectangle constructor only accepts integer values (hence while I multiplied with 6). This results in a fairly inaccurate zooming. ('e' is the mouse pointer position)

Is it possible to give a double value to it somehow, or convert double to int without losing the decimals?

Comment: You can convert the result of the multiplication to an int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use `Convert.ToInt32`, or use a `float` and [`RectangleF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.RectangleF(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
new Rectangle( Convert.ToInt32(e.X*6)
             , Convert.ToInt32(e.Y*6)
             , Convert.ToInt32(zWidth)
             , Convert.ToInt32(zHeight)
             )
```

Or, if you need that little bit extra precision:

```
new RectangleF( Convert.ToFloat(e.X*6)
              , Convert.ToFloat(e.Y*6)
              , Convert.ToFloat(zWidth)
              , Convert.ToFloat(zHeight)
              )
```